# SQL updating a field with a sequential number

Tags: python, sql

I made some changes hopefully for the better I hope. I still get the same results.

My guess is that the loop updates ever row where tl_name_key equals 2 for every cycle through the loop? I have tried several ways but no success..

TIA Roger

Link File entry seq should be updated:  (24, 2, 4, 20, 2, 'Help Link File')

Link File entry seq should be updated:  (25, 2, 5, 20, 2, 'Help Link File')

```
def reseqeunceLinkField():
#resequence link entry sequence field
global citationNameKey

step = 0

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tl_link WHERE tl_name_key = " + str(citationNameKey))
rowCount = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rowCount:
    step = step + 10
    sql2 = " WHERE tl_name_key = "
    print("Step" , step)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE tl_link SET tl_entry_seq = " + str(step) + sql2 + str(citationNameKey))

connection.commit()

print()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tl_link WHERE tl_name_key = " + str(citationNameKey))
resulta = cursor.fetchall()
for rowCount in resulta:
    print("Link File entry seq should be updated: ", rowCount)
```

Comment: You might want to address the fact that you avoided the intro to the [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html) and your code is open to SQL Injection, the largest hacking issue on the planet, before solving this. It'll also fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!!
Just in case anyone else needs this same thing.

```
def reseqeunceLinkField():
#resequence link entry sequence field
global citationNameKey

step = 0

#get number of rows for citation
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tl_link WHERE tl_name_key = " + str(citationNameKey))
row_count = cursor.fetchall()
#loop through and change entry sequency number
for row in row_count:
    step_number = row[0]
    #print (step_number)
    step = step + 10

    cursor.execute("UPDATE tl_link SET tl_entry_seq =  " \
                   + str(step) \
                   + " WHERE tl_name_key = " + str(citationNameKey) \
                   + " AND tl_key = " + str(step_number))

connection.commit()

#print for testing only
print()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tl_link WHERE tl_name_key = ?" , str(citationNameKey))
resulta = cursor.fetchall()
for rowCount in resulta:
    print("Link File entry seq should be updated: ", rowCount)
```